# using 3 versions jQuery for plugins and noConflict not working

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

The two plugins I'm using use different versions of jQuery. I have successfully used noConflict() to get them to work together but now I want to use Foundation 5's modal to announce to mobile users that this site is best viewed in landscape. I could use, and may have to, a simple alert but the styled partially transparent modal looks lots better. Including Foundation's jQuery("bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js") breaks them both however, and I cannot seem to get noConflict to solve it.

I load the first version of jQuery used for the parallax plugin I'm using, then include the plugins. Further down in the body I use noConflict for the second version of jQuery used by the GridThumbnailPreview plugin, but I had to go into the js file(grid.js) and change every instance of '$' to 'jquery2' to get it to work. So far so good.

Then I add a function call to a jQuery script that checks to see if we are in portrait and fires a modal to alert the user to use landscape. This breaks the two plugins and I can't seem to do anything with noConflict to solve it. Here is the relevant code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#nav').localScroll(800); 
$('#intro').parallax("50%", 0.1);
$('#media').parallax("50%", 0.1);
$('.bg').parallax("50%", 0.4);
$('#world').parallax("50%", 0.3);

})
</script>
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>var jquery2 = jQuery.noConflict(  );</script>
    <script src="js/grid2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            Grid.init();
        });
</script>
...
```

This Works fine up to here until I try to add Foundation's jQuery:

```
 <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"> </script>
<script>
    var jQueryBower = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
 <script >$(document).foundation();</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    landscapeAlert();
});
```

When I add Foundation's jQuery it breaks the previous 2 plugins but the Foundation modal doesn not work, if I add the 'var jQueryBower = jQuery.noConflict();' call then the previous two plugins work again but the Foundation modal no longer works. I have tried using 'true' with noConflict to no avail. Help?

Comment: absurd to even think of 3 versions. The norm is to only load one, why do you think you need 3?

Comment: Why is 2 the limit? I'm assuming jQuery has the noConflict function for a reason. Does it only work for two?

Comment: wouldn't you want to use the jQueryBower.foundation()

Comment: You mean jQueryBower.foundation() ? Tried it didn't work. Tried it our way too.....no go.

Comment: you can try in the console to see what variable is pointing to which jquery. try just typing $, then jQueryBower, and finally jQuery2. each log should show you which version is loaded

Comment: Sorry got that wrong try $().jquery, jQueryBower().jquery, and jQuery2().jquery. If that doesn't work try $.fn.jquery and the like

Comment: I fixed it. Not sure if there's a limit of how many times you can use noConflict on a page, seems to be two from what I'm seeing. I just simply used noConflict on the first two versions of jQuery and left Foundation's version alone.